# How does this formula for calculating the "mass sum" in a collision translate to 3D?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, collision, rigid-body-dynamics

According [this tutorial](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/custom-2d-physics-engine-oriented-rigid-bodies--gamedev-8032), formula number 5:

$$j = \frac{-(1 + e)((V^{A} - V^{B}) * t)}{\frac{1}{mass^{A}} + \frac{1}{mass^{B}}}$$

translates into formula number 6:

$$j = \frac{-(1 + e)((V^{A} - V^{B}) * t)}{\frac{1}{mass^{A}} + \frac{1}{mass^{B}} + \frac{(r^{A} \times t)^{2}}{I^{A}} + \frac{(r^{B} \times t)^{2}}{I^{B}}}$$

when dealing with oriented bodies. $j$ is a scalar by which you divide normal and friction impulses to simulate them.
This is only valid for the 2D case, though, where the inertia is a scalar. What if I have the inertia as a tensor (more specifically a 3x3 matrix)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the similar tutorial in:

1. http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~baraff/sigcourse/notesd1.pdf
2. http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~baraff/sigcourse/notesd2.pdf

To get $$ \boxed{ J=\dfrac{(\boldsymbol{\epsilon}+1)\;\left(\vec{n}^{\top}\vec{v}_{rel}^{-}\right)}{\frac{1}{m_{2}}+\frac{1}{m_{1}}+\vec{n}^{\top}\left[\left(\frac{\vec{d}_{2}\times\vec{n}}{I_{2}}\right)\times\vec{d}_{2}+\left(\frac{\vec{d}_{1}\times\vec{n}}{I_{1}}\right)\times\vec{d}_{1}\right]}
} $$

where *vector/matrix* equals to *matrix*<sup>-1</sup>**vector*, and × is the vector cross product.

Comment: Also found this equation in http://chrishecker.com/images/b/bb/Gdmphys4.pdf page 24.

Comment: What exactly is $n^T$? As I've understood it, it simply makes the normal multiply with the rest of the line. I tried to implement this as follows (in code), but it doesn't seem to work:


`ra = contact_point - a.position;`
`rb = contact_point - b.position;`

`inverse_mass_sum = a.inverse_mass + b.inverse_mass +
   dot(normal, cross(a.inverse_inertia * cross(ra, normal), ra) + cross(b.inverse_inertia * cross(rb, normal), rb));`

Where `inverse_mass_sum` is the denominator that I use for friction and impulse calculations.

Comment: $\vec{a}^\top\vec{b} = \vec{a}\cdot\vec{b} =$ scalar product.

Comment: $I_1$ and $I_2$ are 3×3 mass moment of inertia matrices.